# What's the difference between proxy and firewall?

Tags: intranet

What's the difference between proxy and firewall? And can we integrate a nat or pat into a proxy or firewall?

Answer (score 5):

A [Proxy Server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server) is a device that:

> acts as an intermediary for requests from clients seeking resources from other servers.

A [Firewall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firewall_(computing)) is a device that is:

> designed to permit or deny network transmissions based upon a set of rules

The former just lets all traffic through regardless of source or destination and is a way of routing requests through known gateways and is often used to allow companies to log network traffic for example.

A proxy *may* include a firewall as part of it's functionality but it doesn't have to.

I would expect that [Network Address Translation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation) (NAT) and Port Address Translation (PAT) - which is basically the same thing - would be functionality that *could* be built in, but NAPT is more used on routers etc. to:

> However it is common to hide an entire IP address space, usually consisting of private IP addresses, behind a single IP address (or in some cases a small group of IP addresses) in another (usually public) address space.

Comment: ok! can we integrate a nat/pat into a proxy or firewall?

Comment: @samia - probably, but I'm not sure what "pat" stands for.

Comment: @Chris - pat is port address translation.

Comment: @Matt - cheers.

Comment: @Chrisf (Port Adress Translation) like a nat(Network @ Transltion) used to associate a public adress to private ones to allow access on internet! becoz in our machines we have private @ and to access internet we need a public one!!! That's why a nat/pat are used for ;)

Comment: @samia - you don't need PAT as such. NATing will do what you need with almost all firewall scenarios

Comment: NAT/PAT is something a router does, not a proxy or firewall. A firewall can block and open ports, the router actually does the traffic direction that you see with NAT/PAT.

Comment: @Rory: sorry but having a nat in such company is not enough to translate all private @!I think we need a pat to identify the location of a node in a network using its port otherwise when receiving a msg to send it to an x internal machine a nat cannot identify the destination??? If i'm wrong say to me please!

Comment: Unless you have a very strange port lockdown on your machines NAT will absolutely do what you need. PAT is more for when you have a specific port restriction, but not commonly used the way you are describing

Comment: I can't underestand what you mean? could u pleaz repeate what's the difference between these 2 eqpmnt that you see?

Answer (score 1):

> And can we integrate a nat or pat into a proxy or firewall?

Yes, Microsoft's Threat Management Gateway (TMG) is an example of a proxy & firewall wrapped into one.

Comment: Hi uSlackr - could you revise answer to explain the differences?

Comment: My answer is to the second part of his question.  They can be integrated.

Comment: good point, I will change the vote.

Answer (score 1):

Proxies are used explicitly, for example a browser is configured to forward http requests to a proxy. A firewall is used implicitly, for example to drop some network connections. NAT works at the network level. NAT uses the same mechanisms as a stateful firewall to let a few machines appear with a single external IP address. Conceptually that makes NAT closer to a firewall. On the other hand the fact that a NAT rewrites packets (changing ports and addresses) is similar to a proxy changing ports and addresses and adjusting headers before relaying a request.

Comment: thank u! How to make an internal or a private network more secure, efficient and functional? Do we have to configurate all these equipmnt : PAT/NAT,Proxy,Firewall...???

Comment: Not all proxies are explicit. Consider the transparent proxy. Clients are not configured to use it, but their traffic is routed through it.

Comment: @Xenoactive This kind of thing needs a different name. The HTTP spec [defines proxies](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-1.3) as used explicitly, and transparent proxies as proxies that don't alter the requests at all.